# How to show Flash messages across webpages using flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to enter flash messages for actions of the user in a website. But the flash messages are not shown for some reason. Here is the [repository](https://github.com/thumulakaru/Unit-4-project/tree/main). I checked the endpoint several times and the logic seemed to working fine. I'll attach a part of the code below but for the full version you might have to go to the repository.

**The code of the header:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% endif %}
    {% if description %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
    {% endif %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='prism.css') }}">
    {% block css%}{% endblock %}
</head>
<style>
    .alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
    .h1{
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
<div class = "container">
<header class="p-3 mb-3 border-bottom fixed-top" style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; background-color: #000000;">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
      <img src="https://icons.veryicon.com/png/o/education-technology/educational-icon/physics-4.png" alt="" width="100" height="100">
        <h1  class="ms-3 mb-0" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Phy6hub</h1><h4 style="color:#FFFFFF";>Connect with the cosmos</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <ul class="nav me-3">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link link-secondary" href="/dashboard"><img src="../static/home_icon.png"></a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link link-body-emphasis" href="/my_profile"> <img src="../static/profile_icon.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="d-flex" style = "padding-right: 30px">
     <a href = "/new_post"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2 btn-lg" style="background-color: #39FF14; border: #39FF14">New Post</button></a>
        <a href="/logout"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Logout</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</div>
<body style="background-color: black">
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ message[1] }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ message[0] }}</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
<div style="margin-top: 140px;">
{% block content%}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-dark" style="background-color: #212529">
  <div class="container" style="background-color: #212529">
    <div class="row" style="color: white">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white">
            {% if message %}
          <div class="mb-3" >
          <span class="text-secondary">Currently logged in as {{ username }}</span>
        </div>
            {% endif %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">Made by Thumula Karunaratne</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">Phy6hub for ISAK&copy; 2023</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-qKXV1j0HvMUeCBQ+QVp7JcfGl760yU08IQ+GpUo5hlbpg51QRiuqHAJz8+BrxE/N"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='prism.js') }}"></script>

</html>
```

**The code of the home page:**

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}


{% block css %}
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: "Source Code Pro", sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .post {
            border: 2px solid #39ff14;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .post .title{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .post .user_and_datetime {
            font-style: italic;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .post .content {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .post .like-button {
            background-color: #39ff14;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        .post .dislike-button {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 100px;
        }
        .post .likes-count {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            right: 60px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
<body style="background-color: black">

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <div class="input-group rounded">
                <form method="get">
                  <input type="search" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" name = "search"/>
                    <button><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href="?sort_by="></ahref><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"> Remove sort</button></a>
            <a href="?sort_by=time"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"> Sort by date</button></a>
            <a href="?sort_by=like"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Sort by likes</button></a>
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="">
                    <h1>Welcome Back {{ username }}!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="title" style="color: white">{{ post.title }}</div>
            <div class="user_and_datetime" style="color: white">Posted by {{ post.user }} at {{ post.time }}</div>
            <div class="content" style="color: white">{{ post.content }}</div>
            <p style="color: white"> <i>What should we do to this question's velocity towards the IB students?</i></p>
            <a href="/add_accl/{{post.id}}"><button formmethod="get" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm w-auto">Accelerate</button></a>
            <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ post.likes }}</span>
            <a href="/add_dece/{{post.id}}"><button formmethod="get" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm w-auto">Decelerate</button></a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**Endpoint code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, session
from datetime import datetime
import os
from jinja2 import Environment

from token_manager import generate_token, get_username_from_token, check_token
from db_handler import database_handler as dbh
from password_handler import *
from validations import validate_email, validate_password

app = Flask(__name__)
db = dbh("networking.db")

app.jinja_env.filters['strfttime'] = datetime.strftime
env = Environment()
env.filters['strftime'] = datetime.strftime
secret_key = os.urandom(32)
app.secret_key = secret_key


def error_handler():
    flash(("User timed out. Please try again", "danger"))
    return redirect(url_for("login"))


@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET"])
def dashboard():
    try:
        token = session["token"]
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        # Defining the variable 'sort_by'
        sort_by = request.args.get('sort_by', default="", type=str)
        # Run only when the user is given an input
        if request.method == "GET":
            search_in = request.args.get("search")
            # To avoid running into an error when querying
            if search_in is None:
                # To avoid running into an error when querying
                search_in = ""
            posts = db.search_posts_by_x(sort_by, search_in)
            return render_template("post_template.html",username = username, posts = posts)

    except KeyError:
        flash(("User timed out. Please try again", "danger"))
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


@app.route('/')
def landing_check():  # Redirection to the login page
    try:
        # To make sure that there's no token created
        token = session['token']
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    except KeyError:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    print(request.method)
    result = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        uname_check = db.username_exists(uname)
        if uname_check:
            db_object = db.get_user(uname)
            db_password = db_object.password
            pass_state = check_password(password, db_password)
            if pass_state:  # If the password is correct
                uname = db_object.username
                flash("Logged in successfully", "success")
                user = db.get_user(uname)
                session["token"] = generate_token(user.username, 120)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard', username=user.username))

            else:
                flash(("Wrong password", "danger"))
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

        else:
            flash(("User does not exist", "danger"))
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/registration", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def registration():
    message = ""
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":  # Register button pressed
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["psw"]
        password2 = request.form["psw-repeat"]
        username = request.form["username"]

        if validate_email(email): # Email validation
            if not db.username_exists(username): # Check if username exists in the database
                print(db.email_exists(email))
                if not db.email_exists(email):
                    if validate_password(password):
                        if password == password2:
                            hashed_pwd = hash_password(password)
                            db.insert_user(email, username, hashed_pwd)
                            flash(("User created successfully", "success"))
                            return redirect(url_for("login"))

                        else:
                            flash(("Passwords do not match", "danger"))
                            return redirect(url_for("registration"))
                    else:
                        flash(("The password has to be between 8 and 32 characters", "danger"))
                        return redirect(url_for("registration"))
                else:
                    flash(("Email already exists", "danger"))
                    return redirect(url_for("registration"))
            else:
                flash(("The username already exists", "danger"))
                return redirect(url_for("registration"))
        else:
            print("why?")
            flash(("Please enter a valid email address", "danger"))
            return redirect(url_for("registration"))
    else:
        return render_template("registration.html")


@app.route("/new_post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def new_post():
    try:
        token = session["token"]
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        if request.method == "POST":
            title = request.form["title"]
            content = request.form["content"]
            if title.strip() != "":
                if content.strip() != "":
                    temp_result = db.insert_post(username, title, content)
                    if not temp_result:
                        flash(("The title already exists", "danger"))
                        return redirect(url_for("new_post"))
                    else:
                        flash(("Post added successfully", "success"))
                        return redirect(url_for("my_profile", username=username))
                else:
                    flash(("The content cannot be empty", "danger"))
            else:
                flash(("The title cannot be empty", "danger"))

        elif request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("new_post.html", username=username)

    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()


@app.route("/my_profile")
def my_profile():
    try:
        token = session["token"]
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        user = db.get_user(username)
        posts = db.get_own_posts(username)
        return render_template("profile.html", posts=posts, username=username, user=user)

    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()


@app.route("/change_password", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def change_password():
    try:
        token = session["token"]
        username = get_username_from_token(token)
        if check_token(token):
            if request.method == "POST":
                user = db.get_user(username)
                old_pw = request.form["old_pw"]
                new_pw_1 = request.form["new_pw_1"]
                new_pw_2 = request.form["new_pw_2"]
                if check_password(old_pw, user.password):
                    if validate_password(new_pw_1):
                        if new_pw_1 == new_pw_2:
                            temp_pass = hash_password(new_pw_1)
                            db.change_pswd(username, temp_pass)
                            flash(("Password changed successfully", "success"))
                            return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))

                        else:
                            flash(("New passwords do not match", "danger"))
                            return redirect(url_for("change_password"))
                    else:
                        flash(("The new password must be between 8-32 characters", "danger"))
                        return redirect(url_for("change_password"))
                else:
                    print("stuck at here")
                    flash(("Wrong password", "danger"))
                    return redirect(url_for("change_password"))

            elif request.method == "GET":
                return render_template("change_password.html", username = username)



    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route("/add_accl/<int:post_id>")
def add_like(post_id):
    try:
        token = session['token']
        if check_token(token):
            db.add_like_or_dislike(post_id, "like")
            return redirect(request.referrer)
        else:
            return error_handler()
    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()


@app.route("/add_dece/<int:post_id>")
def add_dislike(post_id):
    try:
        token = session['token']
        if check_token(token):
            db.add_like_or_dislike(post_id, "dislike")
            return redirect(request.referrer)
        else:
            return error_handler()
    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()


@app.route("/delete/<int:post_id>")
def delete_post(post_id):
    try:
        token = session["token"]
        if check_token(token):
            db.delete_post(post_id)
            return redirect(request.referrer)
            flash(("Post was deleted successfully", "success"))
        else:
            return error_handler()
    except KeyError:
        return error_handler()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True  # setting the debugging option for the application instance
    app.run()
```

Thanks!

I ran the flask file using pycharm and it ran smoothly with everything except for displaying the flask messages.

Answer (score 0):

To show messages categorized, there is a separate section in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/flashing/#flashing-with-categories).

You pass a tuple consisting of a message and a category to the `flash` command.
However, in this case, the command expects two separate arguments. First the message, followed by the category.

```py
flash("User timed out. Please try again", "danger")
```

Furthermore, the embedding with categories is as follows.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
   {% if messages %}
     {% for category, message in messages %}
       <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
         <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
       </div>
     {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Please check your HTML structure again.
The `body` tag is intended for single use and encloses the entire displayable part of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- title, styles, etc. -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- content of the page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Here is a simplified example for displaying messages with Flask and Bootstrap 5.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    flash, 
    render_template, 
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('A simple primary alert—check it out!', 'primary')
    flash('A simple secondary alert—check it out!', 'secondary')
    flash('A simple success alert—check it out!', 'success')
    flash('A simple danger alert—check it out!', 'danger')
    flash('A simple warning alert—check it out!', 'warning')
    flash('A simple info alert—check it out!', 'info')
    flash('A simple light alert—check it out!', 'light')
    flash('A simple dark alert—check it out!', 'dark')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link 
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container my-2">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </main>

    <script 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, this did not solve my problem. The flash messages are still not being displayed across webpages.

Comment: I've expanded my answer with a simple example. Hope it helps.